# Number of times a Gaussian process crosses zero in an interval

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian

Using a probabilistic method for number theoretic purposes, I have encountered the following question (it may be very standard):

> Let $X_t$ be a Gaussian process $(t>0)$ such that $X_0=0$. What is the expected number of times for the process to cross zero in the interval $[0,c)$ as a function of $c$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The magic words are "Kac-Rice formula". This is exactly the question which comes up in analyzing zeros of random polynomials.